# How do I change directories using Paramiko?

Tags: python, unix, paramiko

[Drush commands not executing using Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916650/paramiko-stderr-object-wont-reset)

I posted the above question regarding a persistent error message that I receive using Paramiko. I do not think it is related to my next question, but it might be.

I can successfully connect to my server via SSH using Paramiko. I can execute commands like ls or pwd. What I can't seem to do is change directories. I can send the command "cd .." for example, but when I follow up with "pwd" it shows that I haven't changed directories. It just lists the initial directory I am in when I log in.

```
>>> stdin, stdout, stderr = myssh.exec_command("pwd")
>>> stdout.readlines()
['/big/dom/home/myid\n']
>>> stdin, stdout, stderr = myssh.exec_command("cd ../")
>>> stdout.readlines()
[]
>>> stdin, stdout, stderr = myssh.exec_command("pwd")
>>> stdout.readlines()
['/big/dom/home/myid\n']
>>>
```

Am I misunderstanding what is going on here? Should I not be able to change directories? Or if I can, should I be doing it in some other way than using exec_command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you execute multiple commands in a single session in Paramiko? (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203653/how-do-you-execute-multiple-commands-in-a-single-session-in-paramiko-python)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This guy had it figured out: http://www.vertigrated.com/blog/2010/02/python-remote-ssh-with-paramiko/

You just have to send multiple commands with one exec_command, such as:

```
myssh.exec_command('cd ..; pwd')
```

Then stdout.readlines() will return the directory that you changed to.

Comment: I tried to send multiple commands with one exec_command like "ssh.exec_command('cd /usr/soumya/PGMS/;pwd')" , but its not working. Hence i tried to print the stderr output and it is as follows:  ['bash: line 0: cd: /usr/soumya/PGMS/: No such file or directory\n']. The output shows its still in root. "['/root\n']"

Answer (score 10):

Well paramiko creates an instance of shell and all the commands that you wish to execute in paramiko have to be given in that instance of shell only.

For example:
Let us say I have some folder in the directory I am in.

```
folder1
folder2
folder3
```

Now if I want to cd into folder 1 and make a directory there what I would do is:

```
ssh.exec_command('cd folder1;mkdir folder4')
```

if you write it like:

```
ssh.exec_command('cd folder1')
ssh.exec_command('mkdir folder4')
```

you would get the result like

```
folder1
folder2
folder3
folder4
```

as those were two different instances of the shell and would be independent in their function.

Comment: This is a very clear explanation that seems to be accurate based on what I've read from the docs. +1.

Answer (score 8):

As of version 2.6, if you use the SFTPClient, the method to change directories is

 `sftp = myssh.open_sftp()
 sftp.chdir('path/to/directory')`

Comment: This seems like the correct answer for a sufficiently modern version of Paramiko.

Comment: What if you want to use SSHClient instead of SFTPClient? This answer only seems to apply to the latter. If that's the case, could you edit the answer to make this caveat more explicit?

Comment: Thanks @bob, you're absolutely right.  I've edited the answer to be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late with this one, but its possible to 'invoke_shell' and write to the standard input through a file.

Please see:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6203877/1861353

Seems a little bit heavyweight since you can just ';'.join(cmdlist) and send to the exec_command.